# Can we change the Component Title using Core Service?

Tags: core-service

I want to rename thousand of Components based on a Schema. I am trying to build a Core Service application. I am able to get all the Components, but I am not able to change the title. I see several post to change the fields but not the title. Is there any other better way to change the Component Title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the system title of a component by simply using 'Title' property of the ComponentData object.

For example:

`ComponentData component = (ComponentData)coreServiceClient.Read("tcmuri", defaulReadOptions);
component.Title = "new title";
component = (ComponentData)this.coreServiceClient.Save(component, new ReadOptions());
coreServiceClient.CheckIn(id: component.Id, readBackOptions: defaulReadOptions);
component = (ComponentData)this.coreServiceClient.Save(component, new ReadOptions());`

Just found an example also on SDL Docs:
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-AAA1BE79-4EB0-4001-9692-400589A52EF0

Comment: Thanks @shahid, it helped:)

Comment: @NeeleshRaghuvanshi nice, happy coding!